# How do I check default credentials to login in anzograph for the first time?

Tags: rdf, anzograph

I have installed Anzograph via Docker in a Mac OS X, but I can not login to the admin console, I need default(?) login and password

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't the place for questions like this as it isn't related to programming. Please review the docs for this information

Answer (score 3):

The docker images ([AnzoGraph all-in-one](https://hub.docker.com/r/cambridgesemantics/anzograph), [AnzoGraph Frontend](https://hub.docker.com/r/cambridgesemantics/anzograph-frontend), [AnzoGraph DB](https://hub.docker.com/r/cambridgesemantics/anzograph-db)) provide default values to make it as simple as possible to give [anzograph](/questions/tagged/anzograph) a spin.

The images use:

```
ui_admin_user="admin"
ui_admin_password="Passw0rd1"
ui_query_user="query"
ui_query_user_password="Passw0rd2"
grpc_admin_user="admin"
grpc_admin_password="Passw0rd1"
grpc_query_user="query"
grpc_query_user_password="Passw0rd2"
```

as default.

However, we highly recommend using kubernetes for any serious use case. The AnzoGraph helm chart allows you to fully control the activation while deploying a single AnzoGraph DB node or an AnzoGraph DB cluster targeting for example Docker Desktop for Mac (using sufficient resources for the underlying VM and enabled kubernetes).

With activation we refer to boot-strap configuration of an application, so you can use it without manual configuration. In the case of helm managed (kubernetes) releases you define your property values in a values.yaml file you use at deployment time.

Please note, that we have not been able to certify minikube as of yet, but once  [minikube PR 7349](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/7349) is integrated in one of the next minikube releases, we plan to look into it again.

For use cases using AnzoGraph in production, we offer a AnzoGraph as managed (kubernetes-custom-resources) with the [anzograph operator](https://hub.docker.com/r/cambridgesemantics/anzograph-operator).

Answer (score 1):

If you dont change them, these are the defaults.

ui_admin_user="admin"
ui_admin_password="Passw0rd1"

ui_query_user="query"
ui_query_user_password="Passw0rd2"

grpc_admin_user="admin"
grpc_admin_password="Passw0rd1"

grpc_query_user="query"
grpc_query_user_password="Passw0rd2

[anzograph](/questions/tagged/anzograph)

Answer (score 0):

> username: admin
>
> password: Passw0rd1